# How do you update the structure of a network-graph in plotly?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, visualization

I'm just beginning with plotly. I'm following the examples here: [Plotly Network Graph Examples](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/)

However Nowhere is there an explanation/demonstration, how to modify the structure of the graph after the call to fig.show(). Can anybody provide example code,specifically what would come after fig.show() to add/remove nodes and edges, such that the displayed output would update in real-time?

Comment: usually plot modules use some buttons, sliders or other widgets to update data. Eventually you should check if it has some `timer` to run periodically function which update plot

Comment: see [dcc.Interval](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval) and [Live updates](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates)

Comment: as I know `show()` generates HTML+JavaScript and open browser to show it - and later it doesn't have access to this HTML+JavaScript. It would need to run plot with web server (ie. `Dash`, `Flask`) and then JavaScript can send requests to server, server may run Python code, and it may send back response with new data, and JavaScript can get new data and update plot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thx @furas. I found a great explanation here at G4G: [Plot Live Graphs using Python Dash and Plotly](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plot-live-graphs-using-python-dash-and-plotly/). It doesn't use a figure on its own, rather integrates it into dash and uses dash's hot-updates feature